# creating folder in webapp and saving images in that

Tags: java, tomcat, primefaces

Hello friends,

I have the following code to upload a image to my WebApp in folder WebContent-->images-->menuitemimg

```
    private String doUploadFile(String menuItemName,Long menuItemId){
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        String imageName = null;
        try{
            String dirPath = externalContext.getRealPath(File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"menuitemimg");
            File targetFolder = new File(dirPath);
            targetFolder.mkdirs();
            imageName = file.getFileName();
            imageName = menuItemName+"_"+menuItemId+"."+FilenameUtils.getExtension(imageName);
            inputStream = file.getInputstream();
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(targetFolder+File.separator+imageName));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageName;
}
```

The code is just working fine. But when I restart server the images uploaded in menuitemimg folder get vanished. I don't want to store images on disc or in database.  So what I suppose to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not supposed to save images inside your web application as if that's more like a temporary folder which gets refreshed everytime you upload a new WAR file.

Comment: Either save to a different folder(outside war) or to a database.

Comment: Thanks for replay Makky. I will follow your suggesion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through you code, it seems you are storing images inside you project folder itself.
I would suggest you to upload your images somewhere else **outside the container**.